# How do I get Solr 8.11.1 to connect to SQL Server 2016

Tags: solr, sql-server-2016, ojdbc, dataimporthandler, solr8

I'm currently running Solr 8.11.1 on RHEL 8.8 (Ootpa). I have a collection that's successfully pulling data from an Oracle database into Solr.
It does so by using Solr's DataImportHandler and ojdbc6.jar. I've tried creating a new collection to connect to a SQL Server, but haven't had any luck.

I followed a similar approach to how I got my collection that's currently connected to an Oracle Database, which was to do the following:

Steps Attempted to Connect Solr 8.11.1 to connect to SQL Server 2016:

1. I added the DataImportHandler in the solrconfig.xml to include the necessary jar files
   (odbc6.jar, solr-dataimporthandler-8.11.1.jar, and solr-dataimporthandler-extras-8.11.1.jar)

```
<lib dir="/search/solr-8.11.1/server/lib" regex="ojdbc6\.jar"/>
    <lib dir="/search/solr-8.11.1/dist" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar"/>
    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

2. Made sure that the 3 jar files are in the correct locations as specified in the above step.
3. Create the data-config.xml file. This is where I'm not sure. I've seen various "url" formats for SQL Server and tried them all, but still get the same outcome each time.

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://myServer.com\myInstanceName;databaseName=myDB" user="myUser" password="myPassword">
        </dataSource>
        <document name="assets">
                <entity name="item" query="SELECT PHOTO_ID AS id FROM myDB.PHOTOS">
                        <field column="ID" name="id"></field>
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Outcome:
After making all of the above changes, I'll restart Solr and then go to the Solr Admin screen to view the collection I made these changes to.
I then attempt to run a dataimport on that collection, but it doesn't import anything.
It says "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents."

[image: Result]

Any ideas on what I need to correct? Or any tutorials on how to do this? I haven't found much online and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anything in the logs? As per the screenshot, Total requests made to datasource : 0, would mean it is not talking to the datasource.

Comment: I've checked the Solr logs after attempting a data import, but the logs don't show any warnings or errors. I see that it makes an attempt to authorize to the data source, but that's it. I can't find it saying it succeeded or if it didn't. That's why I'm wondering if the format in my data-config.xml is correct or not. I did try different variations from what I found online, but still no luck.

Comment: can you try without the instance name?

url="jdbc:sqlserver://myServer.com;databaseName=myDB"

Comment: I've tried updating the connection string in the data-config.xml file to exclude the instance name as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same results. When I check the logs I still see it making an attempt to connect, but it still doesn't say if it fails or succeeded. I think it's silently failing and is why we see "Total requests made to datasource : 0".

Comment: Ok. Is it possible for you to write a standalone java program and try connecting to the db using jdbc? At least it will confirm whether the issue is with solr or some sort of connectivity issue between your computer and the db server.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update here. I created a standalone Java program that connects to the SQL server database. It works fine when ran locally but fails when I run the jar on the Linux host running Solr with the following error message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
"encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "true" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: 
Error: FIPS mode: only SunJSSE TrustManagers may be used.

Comment: What version of jdk do you use?

Comment: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)

Comment: How about running java with the following option... 
  -Djava.security.disableSystemPropertiesFile=true

Comment: Adding that option to the JVM allowed my standalone Java program to run. It was able to successfully connect to the SQL server and return the data. So it does seem that there is an underlying FIPS issue that's preventing me to connect to the SQL server since using that option allowed it. I thought that by having added the SQL server's cert to my NSS database that it would allow the connect, but I guess I'm also missing something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I can help you further with the FIPS issue. However, it will be worth trying passing the same argument to the jvm when starting SOLR

Comment: Thanks, I tried passing the same argument to the JVM when starting Solr, but that caused Solr to break. Also, I have a requirement to get it to work with FIPS. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'll post back here once we figure out the solution. Thanks again!